# Selecting DataTypes of specific columns Oracle SQl Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I am trying to generate data_types of specific columns.

```
Time        Date        Msg

34.324,  09/13/2011, thankyou,
```

I would like to generate the type of that specific value

e.g

```
VarChar2, Date, varchar2(char 30)
```

I wrote this sql statement below and it works for all the tables

```
Select data_type, column_name, table_name, owner from all_tab_columns;
```

However when I try to access specific tables or column_names or both I only get the headers
like so..

**INPUT**

```
 select data_type, column_name,  owner from all_tab_columns where 
 table_name = 'MyTable' and column_name= 'ColumnOfInterest'
```

**OUTPUT**

```
data_type column_name table_name, owner
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong ?

**OUTPUT From First Query**
      *select data_type, column_name, owner from all_tab_columns*

```
  DATA_TYPE     COLUMN_NAME                    OWNER


VARCHAR2    ColumnName1                        User21
VARCHAR2    CN2                                USER22
NUMBER      CN3                                USER22
VARCHAR2    CN4                                USER21
VARCHAR2    CN5                                USER22
VARCHAR2    CN6                                USER32
```

Comment: Do you have the table and column names in the correct case in your query? By default they appear in upper-case in the data dictionary (unless they were created as quoted identifiers), so a camel-case value like `'MyTable'` would be unusual. You'd see the actual values to use when running the first query, without any filters, though.

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes I have the table and column names in the correct case. 'MyTable' is not the actual name of the table same goes for column_name

Comment: Then it might be useful to show a small sample of the actual output of the first query, and the exact second query that looks for a table/column in that sample, but which finds no rows. There isn't an obvious reason why a filter like that wouldn't do what you expect.

Comment: @AlexPoole I just added an example of just that. Thanks for your help